# File Upload on Firefox with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automated-tests, protractor, jasmine2.0

There have been some answers to this question before and I've tried all of them and but it just isn't clicking for me though.

I'm including my file upload function from my protractor page-object and the html it is supposedly working on.

Can you help me figure out the right way to phrase this so uploads work in Firefox? This works fine in Chrome. I've done so much to it that I don't even know what I'm looking at anymore.

**my test function:**

```
function uploadAFile() {
  var path = require('path');
  var fileToUpload = '/documents/approved.png';
  var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
  // Find the file input element
  var fileElem = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));
  var unhideFileInputs = function () {
    var makeInputVisible = function () {
      fileElem.removeClass('ng-hide');
    };
  };    
  // File Upload functions
  browser.driver.executeScript(unhideFileInputs);
  fileElem.sendKeys(absolutePath);
  //element(by.css('.file-upload-mask')).click();   
}
```

**my html:**

```
<form action="https://www.website.com/datadatadata.php" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid 
ng-invalid-required" data-ng-show="showReceipt()"enctype="multipart/form-data" 
id="receiptForm" method="post" name="receiptForm" target="upload-target">
  <div class="form-group no-margin">
    <label class="control-label ng-binding">
      Upload a receipt!
      <span class="ng-binding ng-hide" data-ng-show="!requireReceipt()">(optional)</span>
    </label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label class="file-upload-mask">
        <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" data-ng-model="fUpload" id="fUpload" name="fUpload" type="file"> 
        <span class="btn-group" data-ng-show="selectedFileName==''">
          <span class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i></span>
          <span class="btn btn-default ng-binding">Click here to upload your receipt</span>
        </span>
      </label> 
      <span class="btn-group ng-hide" data-ng-show="selectedFileName!=''">
        <span class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="clearfUpload()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span> 
        <span class="btn btn-default ng-binding"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <input name="c" type="hidden" value="1234567"> 
    <input name="objName" type="hidden" value="submission1"> 
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value=""> 
    <input name="fieldName" type="hidden" value="receipt1">
  </div>
  <input class="hide ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" data-ng-model="selectedFileName" 
  data-ng-required="requireReceipt()" required="required" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: What happens in firefox, any error(s)? Thanks.

Comment: `ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`

Firefox is notoriously hard to get Protractor to upload files though, because the element to upload to is hidden and Protractor isn't made to go behind the scenes and change styles to make it visible.

I may actually learn to code from this ongoing fiasco.@alecxe